# Why Remix keeps giving "The requested account and/or method has not been authorized by the user" error?

Tags: remix, transactions, remix-tests, method

I keep getting this error but, after a while, the transaction works. Is there any problem with Remix?

Comment: What provider are you using and what method/tx is failing? Can you post the source code so we can see what function works/doesn't?

Comment: I am using `Injected Provider - Metamask`. I have found that this happened with many different trivial functions and if I keep retrying then they work. It seems that something is not being updated quickly when I change accounts, for example.

Comment: Interesting - suggests it maybe to do with the local environment? For arguments sake, have you tried with the desktop installation, does this happen when you use the Berlin VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the latest update but finally this has been fixed.